# Java generics and raw type

Tags: java, generics, parameters, raw-types

When I write the method this way. I get this warning:

> BaseEvent is a raw type. References to generic type BaseEvent
>   should be parameterized

```
@Override
public <T extends BaseEvent> void actionPerformed(T event) { ... }
```

The code still runs fine, although the warning sign is annoying. When I write the code this way the warning goes away.

```
@Override
public <T> void actionPerformed(BaseEvent<T> event) { ... }
```

With the previous message, It doesn't guarantee that  is a subClass of BaseEvent. So I changed it again:

```
@Override
public <T extends EventObject> void actionPerformed(BaseEvent<T> event) { ... }


@Override
public <T extends BaseEvent<T>> void actionPerformed(BaseEvent<T> event) { ... }
```

BaseEvent class is a class I made that extends EventOBject

```
public abstract class BaseEvent<T> extends EventObject
{
    private String eventType;

    // Constructor
    public BaseEvent(Object source, String type) 
    {
        super(source);
        eventType = type;
    }


    public String getEventType()    { return eventType; }   
}
```

All the methods seem to work  fine. But I was wondering which is the better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do you use `T` in `BaseEvent` definition? Define it in the following way

```
public abstract class BaseEvent extends EventObject
```

then you won't get a warning with

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(BaseEvent event) { ... }
```

**UPDATE**

Suppose your `BaseEvent` really required to be parametrized. Then write following

```
@Override
public <T> void actionPerformed(BaseEvent<T> event) { ... }
```

This will give you a parametrized method.

**UPDATE 1**

`It doesn't guarantee that is a subClass of BaseEvent.`

It does. `<T>` is a parameter for method template. This parameter goes to `BaseEvent<T>` which is subclass of `EventObject` by definition.

**UPDATE 2**

Do not use generics at the beginning of your learning. Generics are just for additional self testing. Use raw types. Then when you start to feel them, you will parametrize them correctly.

Comment: You should mention that what you have in the first piece of code `public void actionPerformed(BaseEvent event) { ... }` works the exact same way as what he has in his first piece of code `public <T extends BaseEvent> void actionPerformed(T event) { ... }`. Both take any instance of `BaseEvent`, which of course includes subclasses of `BaseEvent`.

Comment: Hey Dims, thanks for the explanation. I took out the type parameter from BaseEvent. And thanks for clarifying how to use it when needed.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is the one that avoids the warnings and guarantees your type safety at compile time.

If the type of T in BaseEvent doesn't matter, couldn't you just use your first one and parameterize BaseEvent? Do something like:

```
@Override
public <T extends BaseEvent<?>> void actionPerformed(T event) { ... }
```

Alternatively, it looks like your `BaseEvent` class does not actually use `T` for anything - why is it there?

Comment: Your its not needed. So I removed it. Originally I thought it needed to be there so I can keep track the type of event.

Answer (score 1):

The type parameter T is never used in the class definition. You might be able to remove the type parameter from `BaseEvent`:

```
public abstract class BaseEvent extends EventObject { ... }
```

and just define your method without a type parameter:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(BaseEvent event) { ... }
```

Comment: Your right about the class never using T. I removed it and it works fine. Plus looks a lot cleaner